# ParserError in the Pandas concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, concatenation

I scraped some tweets using `twint` module in different csv files. However, I needed to merge them into a single dataframe and csv file.

```
dataframes = [jan, feb, mar]
total = pd.concat(dataframes).reset_index(drop=True)
```

After the concatenation, for a time-series visualization, I tried to convert the objects in the `date` column from `strings` to `datetime` objects.

```
total['date'] = pd.to_datetime(total['date'])
```

However, I faced with this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2084         try:
-> 2085             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
   2086             # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1a4afbc77b66> in <module>
----> 1 total['date'] = pd.to_datetime(total['date'])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    799                 result = result.tz_localize(tz)
    800     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
--> 801         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    802         if not cache_array.empty:
    803             result = arg.map(cache_array)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    176         unique_dates = unique(arg)
    177         if len(unique_dates) < len(arg):
--> 178             cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
    179             cache_array = Series(cache_dates, index=unique_dates)
    180     return cache_array

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    463         assert format is None or infer_datetime_format
    464         utc = tz == "utc"
--> 465         result, tz_parsed = objects_to_datetime64ns(
    466             arg,
    467             dayfirst=dayfirst,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2088             return values.view("i8"), tz_parsed
   2089         except (ValueError, TypeError):
-> 2090             raise e
   2091 
   2092     if tz_parsed is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   2073 
   2074     try:
-> 2075         result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
   2076             data,
   2077             errors=errors,

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1372         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1373     else:
-> 1374         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1375 
   1376 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         if res is None:
--> 649             raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
    650 
    651         if len(res) == 0:

ParserError: Unknown string format: ['ya60binyagidin', 'günaydın', 'boğaziçitutuklanamaz', 'esnaf1marttaacılıyor', 'cizrevahsetbodrumları', 'fakülteyisarayakur', 'aşağıbakmayacağız', 'abdullahkığılıyaboykot', 'ayağakalk', 'cumhurbaskanıi̇stifa', 'boğaziçi']
```

The problem is caused by the concatenation process, I believe, but I couldn't find how to handle it. At this stage, even if I get rid of those rows containing non-convertible to `datetime` objects in the `date` column. Could you please help me?

Thanks for your help already!

Comment: Since your `date` column contains `string` values so try :   `total['date'] = pd.to_datetime(total['date'],errors='coerce')`

Comment: oviously there are strings in your 'date' column that the parser can't parse - e.g. 'ya60binyagidin' is not a date.

Comment: maybe first display this column to see what you really have in this columns. You can also use method `uniq`, `count`, etc. to get more information about values in column. You should't expect that you will have only correct data. So simply `analize` data before you try to use it. Your error shows that you have incorrect values in this column and now you have to decide what to do with wrong values - remove rows, convert to other values, use average value from other rows, use correct value from nearest row, etc.